# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_str_split()

Tags: php

Какие натсройки нужно записать в файл php.ini и где он находиться, что бы покет который я установил sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring, заработал и интерпретор увидел функию?
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6

Comment: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php - не могу разобраться - что да как.

Comment: `sudo phpenmod mbstring`, если используется Апач, то после установки нужно его перезапустить

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) эта функция доступна с `php >= 7.4`, а у Вас `php 7.2.*`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) эта функция доступна с `php >= 7.4`, а у Вас `php 7.2.*`

В качестве замены можно использовать функцию `preg_split` с модификатором `u`

```php
/**
 * split utf-8 string to array of chars
 * @param string $str
 * @return array
 */
function chars_of($str) {
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $str);
}
```